# Apache rewrite all urls that start with

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

there are several questions answered how to rewrite `urls` that start with a certain word or combination

My question is how to `EXCLUDE` all `urls` that start with a word.

In my case  `www.domain.com/knowledgebase.php`

all those urls starting with this should NOT be redirected.
This is because there are different session ids following for example

```
?osCsid=mrm6flfmrcl9gjohiv4947lgs5?article=7
```

**I put it in front of all other redirects:**

```
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/^[^/]+/([0-9]+)$ - [L]
```

**or like this:**

```
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase\.php$ - [L]
```

**or**

```
RewriteRule /knowledgebase\.php$ - [L]
```

but I did not succeed.

Can Anybody point me in the right direction please.

Comment: One of the last two should have done it, but check out the Apache documentation for the `[L]` flag - there may be a case where additional rules are being processed in a different context. The documentation provides an example of how to not rely solely on `[L]`. To troubleshoot, I'd recommend modifying the last rule above to redirect (`[R]`) to something distinct rather than `-` to make sure the rule is even matching in the first place. If it isn't matching then you know to look elsewhere besides the rule itself. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Comment: Thanks for You help.

Then the problem must be hidden somewhere else. The redirects work. I will post updates on the way.
Thanks again :)